# Animating HTML objects that move when text is modified / changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have this code:

```html
<span><img id="user" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img"></span>
<span><h2 id="textToChange">text here</h2></span>
```

When I change #textToChange the #user moves automatically because the text changes and because it's a span it moves it. I would like to animate #user so it will move in a linear animation instead of just getting to the x value.
Is something like to possible to achieve or am I crazy? Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve], which we need to be able to help you. How about you make a snippet with the code you have, try to animate it, and ask us about that _specifically_?

Comment: Edited should be good

Comment: I am a little confused as to exactly what you want: Do you want one above another and one changes its width accordingly to another? **How do you want it to move?**

Comment: Imagine it like this: this is the text and the letter X is the image
this is text X
when I change it to something else for example
this is something else X
you see the X position has changed, I would like that position change to be animated.

Comment: So you've got a text in #textToChange, and when that text changes dynamically, it bumps the image (since it's inline). You want the bumping to be animated instead of instant. Two things: 1) What changes the text? Is there some JS that does that? 2) Why does your code have the image and text in separate spans, with the text coming after? Doesn't that meant the text can't ever move the image?

Comment: Yes that is the idea, the text is being set using JS they are both inline in my code.

Comment: Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hdokfb9/) portray your problem accurately? I changed the HTML around to make the text be inline with the image (which is not what happens with the original code).

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting little problem. Let me break it down into steps:

1. Find the image's current position
2. Find where it needs to move to
3. Move it
4. Change the text

Now, the hard parts are steps 2 and 3.

For step 2, you have to calculate the length of the new text. This is tricky because there are no built-in functions to tell you how wide text will be with a  given set of styles. You pretty much have to create a duplicate element and measure it instead.

For step 3, you have to move the element without causing a jump before or after the text changes. My way of doing this is to use `position: absolute` and set `left` to the current position (thus eliminating any jerking there). I then transition to the correct position using `transform` (doing a little math to account for the current position), for performance. At the end of the transition, take away the `style` attribute and change the text.

One other thing to watch out for is the text jumping around when the image becomes `position: absolute`. For simplicity, I put the entire line in a `display: flex` container. If you don't want to use flex, you can use `inline-block` or `block` on the text and adjust the padding/height so it will keep the proper amount of space.

Here's what I came up with (also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sao7trjo/)):

```js
var $img = document.getElementById('user');
var $text = document.getElementById('textToChange');
var $estimator = document.getElementById('estimator');

var extraWidth = $img.offsetLeft - $text.offsetWidth;

function estimate(text) {
  $estimator.textContent = text;

  var width = $estimator.offsetWidth;

  $estimator.textContent = '';

  return width;
}

document.getElementById('change-text')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    var newText = randomText();

    var left = $img.offsetLeft;

    $img.style.position = 'absolute';
    $img.style.left = left + 'px';
    $img.style.transition = 'transform linear 1s';
    $img.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      $img.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (extraWidth + estimate(newText) - left) + 'px)';

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $text.textContent = newText;
        $img.removeAttribute('style');
      }, 1000);
    });
  });

// For testing
function randomText() {
  var length = Math.floor(Math.random() * 43) + 3;

  return 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet portris noc tefweep'.slice(0, length);
}
```

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

/* For measuring text width. I don't want it to be seen. */
.not-shown {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span id="textToChange">text here</span>
  <img id="user" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img">
</h2>

<h2 class="not-shown"><span id="estimator"></span></h2>

<button id="change-text">Change text</button>
```

*Note that this does not work well if the text goes to multiple lines.* I chose not to worry about that scenario.